# Нахождение ячейки в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

как можно найти ячейку в таблице задав x и y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если самый простой способ, то как-то так.

```js
let table = document.getElementById('my-table');

let findingInTable = function(row, cell) {
  return table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[row].getElementsByTagName('td')[cell].innerHTML;
}

let findingInTableES6 = (row, cell) => table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[row].getElementsByTagName('td')[cell].innerHTML;

console.log(findingInTable(2, 1));
console.log(findingInTableES6(1, 2));


let findingInTableJQ = (row, cell) => $('table#my-table tr:nth-child(' + row + ') td:nth-child(' + cell + ')').html();

console.log(findingInTableJQ(1, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает.

Comment: Всегда рад помочь, если вас не затруднит, то не могли бы вы отметить ответ, как принятый.

Comment: А возможно на Jquery это реализовать?

Comment: @ЗоригтоРаднаев, можно, добавил в ответ

Comment: Не работает for (var x0 = 0; i < game.width; i++) {
            for (var y0 = 0; i < game.height; i++) {
                if (game.field[x0][y0].isMine) {
                    $('#play-table tr:nth-child(' + x0 + ') td:nth-child(' + y0 + ')').addClass("isMine");
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Если у вас есть новые вопросы, советую задать его как новый вопрос, а не писать в комментарии, это первое. Во-вторых, у вас ошибка `for (var x0 = 0; i < game.width; i++)`, итератор объявили один **x0**, а дальше пишите совсем другой  **i**, так что скорее всего ошибка в условиях и циклах.

Answer (score 2):

На `JQuery`

```js
function getCell(x,y){
  var cell = $('table').find('tr').eq(y-1).children('td').eq(x-1);
  return cell;
}
$('button').click(function(){
  $('td').removeClass('active');
  var x = +$('[name=column]').val();
  var y = +$('[name=row]').val();
  getCell(x,y).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
  padding:3px;
  border:1px solid;
  transition:all .2s ease;
}
td.active{
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
<input type="number" min="1" max="3" name="row" placeholder="Ряд" />
<input type="number" min="1" max="3" name="column" placeholder="Колонка" />
<button>Обозначить ячейку</button>
```